# "timeouts": null in terraform state after setting Timeouts: &schema.ResourceTimeout{} in schema

Tags: terraform, terraform0.12+

Context: adding a new resource to TF Provider

After I read HashiCorp's tutorial about [Retries and Customizable Timeouts](https://www.terraform.io/plugin/sdkv2/resources/retries-and-customizable-timeouts) and figuring out the creation (that uses `StateChangeConf`) might take more than default 20 minutes for Create operation I set a custom timeout for a resource:

```
return &schema.Resource{
    CreateContext: fooCreate,
    Schema: map[string]*schema.Schema{...}
    Timeouts: &schema.ResourceTimeout{
        Create: schema.DefaultTimeout(2 * Time.Hour),
    }
},
...
func fooCreate(ctx context.Context, d *schema.ResourceData, meta interface{}) diag.Diagnostics {
    ...
    createStateConf := &resource.StateChangeConf{
        ...
        Timeout: 1 * Time.Hour,
        ...
    }
```

> Important If using a CRUD function with a timeout, any StateChangeConf timeouts should be configured below that duration to avoid returning the SDK context: deadline exceeded error instead of the retry logic error.

If I don't set `Timeouts` my TF state file looks great however after I add them I can see a new `"timeouts": null` attribute which looks a bit sketchy, is that expected?

Funny enough, I think the creation worked perfectly (that took ~1 hour) even before I added this override:

```
Timeouts: &schema.ResourceTimeout{
        Create: schema.DefaultTimeout(2 * Time.Hour),
    }
```

so I wonder whether it's necessary at all.

Comment: Not a great answer so leaving as a comment, but I looked through the provider SDK code for the timeouts. I see in the resource and state code that nothing seems to be set in the state for `timeouts` in the schema, so that would imply why `nil` --> `null` for the state attribute. Whether it is necessary at all depends on the default `timeouts` set for the provider (I see this being set in the unit tests in the provider SDK for example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disclaimer :: By no means, I'm a `golang` expert but I think I've some understanding on this.

I've checked our `tfstate` files based on `azurerm` provider & indeed found `"timeouts": null`  on various resources.

However, having gone through the issue mentioned [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/22810), `null` is indeed expected here. Explanation provided by `hashicorp` team is below..

> The "timeouts" field in the state is only representative of the
> configuration values. Terraform core isn't aware of the default
> values, as those are looked up at runtime by the provider SDK. The
> provider SDK does encode the timeouts into the "private" field for
> later reference however. There was an issue with delete timeout values
> being lost at one point, but that should only show up with an old AWS
> provider as it's been fixed for a few months.

That means, we should be looking at the field `private` rather `timeouts`. In fact, our state file had `"private": "eyJlMmJmYjczMC1lY2FhLTExZTYtOGY4OC0zNDM2M2JjN2M0YzAiOnsiY3JlYXRlIjoxODAwMDAwMDAwMDAwLCJkZWxldGUiOjE4MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAsInJlYWQiOjMwMDAwMDAwMDAwMCwidXBkYXRlIjoxODAwMDAwMDAwMDAwfX0=",`. It's `base64` encoded.

When I decode, I see below output.

```
echo "eyJlMmJmYjczMC1lY2FhLTExZTYtOGY4OC0zNDM2M2JjN2M0YzAiOnsiY3JlYXRlIjoxODAwMDAwMDAwMDAwLCJkZWxldGUiOjE4MDAwMDAwMDAwMDAsInJlYWQiOjMwMDAwMDAwMDAwMCwidXBkYXRlIjoxODAwMDAwMDAwMDAwfX0=" | base64 -d
{"e2bfb730-ecaa-11e6-8f88-34363bc7c4c0":{"create":1800000000000,"delete":1800000000000,"read":300000000000,"update":1800000000000}}
```

The above timeout key is hardcoded string in `terraform-core` from [here](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/blob/d35bc0531255b496beb5d932f185cbcdb2d61a99/internal/legacy/helper/schema/resource_timeout.go#L13). You must see the `crud` level timeouts you specified in your provider in nanoseconds.

Do you see them by decoding `private` field of your tfstatefile?